# How to create find feature using htmlArea in qooxdoo?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I would like to know search feature using htmlArea in qooxdoo.
For Example: If we wanted to find the custom data in browser,editor or etc.. we called the Ctrl+F or edit menu in Find menu. Right...
I would like to create as look like the find and next feature using qx.ui.embed.htmlArea in qooxdoo framework.
I can show the find result with highlight text in htmlArea. 
"I would like to know, if I clicked the next button, automatic scolling and show the find highlight text result and then next,next and show find result in htmlArea."
How can I do?
Sorry my weak english language.
Please help me.

Regards,
MT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to roll your own, I'm afraid. You could use e.g. a TextField to allow entering a string, then search the contents of the TextArea in your JS code, set the selection to the found offset, scoll into view. Then incrementally repeat when the user clicks the "Next" button you provided ... It might be hard to capture Ctrl-F key sequences as the browser might capture those and prevent the page from receiving it.